# Returning promise from reflux store

Tags: es6-promise, refluxjs

I'm working on my first react/reflux app so I may be approaching this problem in completely the wrong way. I'm trying to return a promise from a reflux store's action handler. This is the minimum code that represents how I'm trying to do this. If I display this in the browser, I get an error saying that the promise is never caught, because the result of the onLogin function is not passed back when the action is initiated. What is the best way to do this?

```
var Reflux = require('reflux');
var React = require('react/addons')

const Action = Reflux.createAction();
const Store = Reflux.createStore({
    init: function() {
        this.listenTo(Action, this.onAction);
    },

    onAction: function(username, password) {
        var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject('Bad password');
        });

        return p;
    }
});

var LoginForm = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.connect(Store, 'store')],
    login: function() {
        Action('nate', 'password1').catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e); // This line is never executed
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <a onClick={this.login} href="#">login</a>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<LoginForm />, document.body);
```

Comment: Actions shouldn't have return values. In the action handler in the store (onAction), you should check the credentials and based on your validation result, you can call another action. So you could have two more actions. One for success and one for fail. An alternative is to have your store send a trigger after validation with the result of the validation as your payload. The component should listen to this store event.

Answer (score 2):

Several things seem a bit confused here.

1. `Reflux.connect(Store, 'store')` is a shorthand for listening to the provided store, and automatically set the "store" property of your component state to whatever is passed in your store's `this.trigger()` call. However, your store never calls `this.trigger` so "store" in your component's state will never be updated. Returning a value from your store's action handlers doesn't trigger an update.
2. Stores should listen to actions to update their internal state, and typically then broadcast this state update by calling `this.trigger`. No component is going to get your returned promise from the store's `onAction` unless it explicitly calls `Store.onAction` (and then it doesn't matter if the actual action was invoked or not).
3. Async work should typically happen in the action's `preEmit` hook, not in the store. You should then also declare the action as async in `createAction` by setting the `asyncResult` option to `true` to automatically create "completed" and "failed" child actions. Check out the Reflux documentation [here](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs#asynchronous-actions) to learn about async events. Async actions automatically return promises, whose `resolve` and `reject` are called when the "completed" and "failed" sub-actions are called respectively. This is a bit opinionated, but that is definitely what I perceive is the intended Reflux way.